# How to connect my fingerprint device to my Login and Register script

Tags: javascript, php

**How to connect my fingerprint device to my Login and Register script.**

my device is Digital Persona 4000b and im using PHP and MSQL in my code

I already tried searching in google but still can't find the solutions

Comment: what -have- you done?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your users to use a Digital Persona to login to a web-page using their browser, they are going to need to install a browser plugin (since neither java or javascript alone wouldn't give access in that way to the usb-ports, see [How to get USB devices List from Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743100/how-to-get-usb-devices-list-from-browser)).

If there is such a browser-plugin, you'd need to check it's api to see how it communicates with javascript. From there on communication to the server-side results the familiar communication options (forms, ajax, etc).

You also might attempt to create a plugin yourself, have a look at [One Touch for Windows SDK Java Developer Guide](http://www.digitalpersona.com/uploadedFiles/Support/Reference_Material/Guides/SDK_Guides/One-Touch-for-Windows-SDK-Java-Developer-Guide.pdf) for example.

You can also contact the manufacturer, since you paid for the device and are going to support it in your application.

Hope this helps!