# Detect if a USB device is plugged in Javascript from browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

Is there Javascript based mechanism with which i can detect, through a browser, that a user has a specific usb device plugged in?

Comment: short answer: no. That would be a hacker's dream

Comment: no, the browser does not expose such information about the machine it's on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For security reasons, JavaScript in web browsers provides only **restricted** access to computer resources. It is **not possible** to store files in an arbitrary folder, start applications or communicate with a **USB** device.

But there are some exceptions :

- In legacy browsers such as IE6 ~ IE8 you can use ActiveX objects or Java applets to achieve this .
- Use a [chrome.usb](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb) API .
- Write a browser plugin using [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) , ([Here, it is not for long though](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html))

**2023 Edit**

The USB interface of the [WebUSB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USB) provides attributes and methods for finding and connecting USB devices from a web page.

( browser support is still limited, for more information refer to browser compatibility table )

Example code:

```js
navigator.usb.getDevices().then((devices) => {
  console.log(`Total devices: ${devices.length}`);
  devices.forEach((device) => {
    console.log(
      `Product name: ${device.productName}, serial number ${device.serialNumber}`
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: is the chrome.usb API only for chrome web apps?

Comment: Yes, this API provides access to USB operations from within the context of an app.

Answer (score 2):

Your javascript code is sand boxed and therefore cannot access system resources such as usb devices.

I think the only way to access the USB devices would be to write a browser plugin. 
[How to get USB devices List from Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743100/how-to-get-usb-devices-list-from-browser)